# Get the height of an attached image in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to get the height of an image attached to a message in discord.py. Here is my code:

```
if message.content(discord.Attachment.height > 0):
  await message.channel.send('Your media file is restricted!')
```

When run, it gives me the following error:

```
error: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'member_descriptor' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`discord.Attachment.height` is a descriptor of the `height` member of the object `discord.Attachment`. This doesn't refer to any specific object, so you're going to need to get the `height` property of a specific attachment on a specific message.

To get the height of a message's attachment:

1. Get the list of attachments on the message using [message.attachments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.attachments). This will be a list of objects of type [discord.Attachment](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment). Note that if there are no attachments, this list will be empty.
2. Get the height of a specific attachment. For example, if the message has one attachment you would use:

```
message.attachments[0].height
```

Note that the height attribute is only applicable to images and videos. You may need to check that the filetype is correct using the `filename` member of `discord.Attachment`